# Using the related function in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to do this condition in a new Power BI column, the "db_user" and "db_user_tran" tables are related to each other in a many-to-one relationship (*:1), but when trying to execute this function, the following appears error:

"The column db_user_tran[cd_idfr_usu] does not exist or does not have a relationship with any table available in the current context."

This is the condition I'm trying to do:

```
Function =
IF(
     NOT(ISBLANK('db_user'[cd_idfr_usu])) && ISBLANK('db_user'[ts_atvc]),
     "TP",
     IF(
         NOT(ISBLANK(db_user'[cd_idfr_usu])) && NOT(ISBLANK('db_user'[ts_atvc])),
         "TPA",
         IF(
             NOT(ISBLANK(RELATED('db_user_tran'[cd_idfr_usu]))),
             "TPH",
             BLANK()
         )
     )
)
```

What it seems is that the error is in the third IF condition, because if I try to execute only the first and second IF conditions, the formula works correctly, the error is giving when I try to call data from another table, namely "db_user_tran" . Where could I be going wrong with this?

What it seems is that the error is in the third IF condition, because if I try to execute only the first and second IF conditions, the formula works correctly, the error is giving when I try to call data from another table, namely "db_user_tran" . Where could I be going wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

`RELATED` only works to a many-to-one or one-to-one relationship. In your case it is one-to-many as `'db_user_tran'` could have multiple rows to the one `'db_user'` row.

For your last conditional, you can replace it with something along the lines of:

```
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('db_user_tran'), NOT(ISBLANK('db_user_tran'[cd_idfr_usu])) ) > 0, "TPH"
```

You could also use a `SWITCH(TRUE(), <condition>, <value> ...)` instead of nested IF statements.

```
Function = 
  SWITCH(TRUE(),
    NOT(ISBLANK('db_user'[cd_idfr_usu])) && ISBLANK('db_user'[ts_atvc]), 
      "TP",

    NOT(ISBLANK(db_user'[cd_idfr_usu])) && NOT(ISBLANK('db_user'[ts_atvc])),
      "TPA",

    CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('db_user_tran'), NOT(ISBLANK('db_user_tran'[cd_idfr_usu])) ) > 0,
      "TPH"
  )
```